# How to get reactive publisher data in a collection of set and set this in another reactive publisher object class

Tags: spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-data-couchbase

I have two document model class. One is RuleSet and another is Rule. 
One RuleSet can have many rules. But When we are saving, We are saving Rules in a diffrent document and RuleSet in different document.

When rest api call /ruleSet uri to get all detail of ruleSet, 
I want to call ruleSetRepository.findAll() which returns Flux

and

then I want to call ruleRepository.findAll() and collect all rule as List

then

ruleSet.SetRules(list of rules from ruleRepository).

I need a code example to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done roughly like this

```
rulesRepository
            .findAll()
            .collectList()
            .map(l -> {
                RuleSet ruleSet = new RuleSet("myRuleSet");
                ruleSet.setRules(l);
                return rulesSetRepository.save(ruleSet);
            })
```

The `rulesRepository.findAll` would return a flux and `collectList` would transform it to a `Mono<List<>>` which can be mapped to Mono returned by save using the list. This code should be customized to handle synchronization and error handling.